# Getting Connection timeout when mock object is called - Mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

Here is my test code:

```
@Mock
AccessTokenCacheService accessTokenCacheService

@InjectMocks
CorrectionService correctionService;

@Test
void test() throws URISyntaxException {
  when(accessTokenCacheService.getCacheAccessToken(anyString())).thenReturn("token-abc");
  RequestClient requestClient = mock(RequestClient.class, withSettings().mockMaker(MockMakers.INLINE));
  ApiResponse apiResponse = mock(ApiResponse.class, withSettings().mockMaker(MockMakers.INLINE));
  when(requestClient.send(any(), any())).thenReturn(apiResponse);
  when(apiResponse.getData()).thenReturn(new BookingDetails());
  assertAll(() -> correctionService.getBooking("id1", "New York"));
}
```

As you can see I'm creating mock objects for `RequestClient` and `ApiResponse` (both are final classes, referring to a separate library)

Inside `correctionService.getBooking()` method, I call `apiResponse.getData()` to get the data. So, I added `when` condition to return a dummy object.

But, this is not working as expected. The test runs for a minute and ends with connection timeout exception.

`java.net.http.HttpConnectTimeoutException: HTTP connect timed out`

`requestClient.send()` makes an HTTP call internally, but since I'm mocking it, I don't see a problem there. What am I doing wrong here?

`RequestClient` is typed class. And, within the `CorrectionService`, we can have multiple types of `RequestClient` like `RequestClient<T1>`, `RequestClient<T2>` created by accessing different methods in the `CorrectionService`.

And I create `RequestClient object` like this:

```
RequestClient<T> requestClient = new RequestClient<>(new HttpClientFactory());
```

And then I use:

```
ApiResponse<T> apiResponse = requestClient.send(request, T.class);
```

I want to mock the utility response `apiResponse` so that I don't make the actual `http` call. I want to mock that, so that actual HTTP call would not happen.

Comment: You haven't injected `requestClient` into `correctionService`.

Comment: @tgdavies just updated data in the post. Let me know if that clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

The mocked `RequestClient` is supposed to be the dependency of the `CorrectionService` ?

But I don't see it to be injected into `CorrectionService` and so it is most probably still using a real `RequestClient` rather than a mock.

Highly recommend to refactor `CorrectionService` to be more testable such that there are some ways to pass a `RequestClient` to it such as through constructor injection :

```java
public CorrectionService(AccessTokenCacheService accessTokenCacheService, RequestClient restClient) {}
```

Then you can do it by :

```java
class FooTest {


    @Mock
    AccessTokenCacheService accessTokenCacheService;

    @Mock(mockMaker=MockMakers.INLINE)
    RequestClient restClient;

    @InjectMocks
    CorrectionService correctionService;

}
```

Refer to [`@InjectMocks`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) for details about the other way to inject the mock. Or keep it simple to do it by yourself rather than using `@InjectMocks`

Comment: `RequestClient` is typed class. Meaning, within the `CorrectionService`, we can have multiple types of `RequestClient` like `RequestClient<T1>`, `RequestClient<T2>` created by accessing different methods in the `CorrectionService`.

Comment: And I create `RequestClient` object like this: `RequestClient<T> requestClient = new RequestClient<>(new HttpClientFactory());`

And then I use:
`ApiResponse<T> apiResponse =
        requestClient.send(request, T.class);`

So, how do I mock this `send()` method? It is not an autowired dependency in `CorrectionService`

Comment: Think of it is a call to utility library. I want to mock that, so that actual HTTP call would not happen.

Comment: ok. update my answer. suggest to refactor `CorrectionService` to make it more testable such that it has some ways to pass the `RequestClient` to it .

Comment: I followed exactly what you mentioned. But the library API is still getting called instead of returning mock response. Can you take a look at this gist?
https://gist.github.com/rahulraj90/bc596de8609cf4248b2f5411b14c7a15

Comment: you are creating a new RequestClient instance in getBooking() (i.e line 16) , which override the RequestClient you pass through constructor. So remove it please

Comment: okay, let me make the changes and test it.